# I am trying to create a Java API which will deploy application war file in running jetty server.

Tags: jetty

I am trying to create a Java API which will deploy application war file in running jetty server.

I don't want to just copy the application war file in webapps directory. Can someone help me on this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        int port=8080;
        Server runningInstance = new Server(8080);
//      String originId="";
//      ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(runningInstance);
        Monitor monitor = new Monitor(8080, "test");
        monitor.start();
        DeploymentManager manager = new DeploymentManager();

        WebAppProvider provider = new WebAppProvider();
        provider.setMonitoredDirName("/Users/Swadebesh/Software/warfiles");
        manager.addAppProvider(provider);

    }
```

I just copied the sample program, I am trying to create. But this program is trying to create a server rather than getting hold of the existing running Jetty instance.